# JFrame becomes gray when using BufferedImage

Tags: java

So when trying to create a new game and importing a png via BufferedImage the JFrame becomes gray and the various objects I painted on it in other classes disappear. I can share other classes if needed but I don't see a reason this shouldnt work.

```
public class Panel extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
 private Teeto game;
 private Player player;
 private Shrooms shroom;
 BufferedImage img;

 public Panel(Teeto game) {
  setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  this.game = game;
  player = new Player(100, (game.HEIGHT / 2) - 100, 200, KeyEvent.VK_UP, KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
  shroom = new Shrooms(100);
  Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);
  timer.start();
  addKeyListener(this);
  setFocusable(true);

  try {
   img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\Patrick\\Desktop\\Teeto\\Yasuo.png"));
  } catch (IOException e) {}
 }

 public void update() {
  player.update();
  shroom.update();
  checkIntersection();
 }

 public void checkIntersection() {
  if (player.getBounds().intersects(shroom.getBounds())) {
   player.health = player.health - 20;
  }
 }

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  update();
  repaint();
 }

 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
  player.pressed(e.getKeyCode());
 }

 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
  player.released(e.getKeyCode());
 }

 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

 @Override
 public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  player.paint(g);
  shroom.paint(g);
  g.drawImage(game.getPanel().img, 0, 0, null);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears your application can't find the file "Yasuo.png". Ensure it resides in the same folder as your class files.

Comment: It does but let me try specifing the path (Yep got no change).

Comment: @JavaBeginner If your image acts as a backgorund, you should paint it first and then your object over it. Does it help?

Comment: No, unfortunately it's still just a grey Jframr with nothing in it.